# Finding how variable affect output of time-series random-forest regression model

Tags: r, machine-learning, time-series, random-forest, prediction

I created a Random-Forest Regression model for time-series data in R that have three predictors and one output variable.

Is there a way to find (perhaps in more absolute terms) how changes in a specific variable affect the prediction output?

I know about variable importance, I am not trying to find the variables that have the biggest effect instead I am trying to see if I pick input variable X_1 and increase its value (or decrease it) how that would change the prediction output.

Does it even makes sense to do this? or is it even possible with a random-forest model? Rereading my question a few times it made me dubious, but any insight/recommendation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess what this question is actually about is called **exploratory data analysis (EDA)**. For starters, I would calculate the **correlations** between the variables to get a feeling for the strength of the [linear] relationship between two variables. Further, I would look at **scatter plots** between the variables to get a feeling for the relationships. Depending on the variables **[linear] regression** could tell how an increase in variable *x1* would affect variable *x2*.